# Automatically click the button for you if there is a date

Tags: php

I have a file called `file.php` which has:

```
$row2= pg_fetch_array($result2);
$website = 'http://validate/?id='.$newDateString;


  <tbody>

    <tr>

     <td><?php echo'<a href="'.$website.'">'. $row['name']; ?></td>
```

The code sends to a file named `jasmine.php` the url with the date since jasmine contains a calendar. It sends it when you click on the date which contains a link to jasmine.

```
Jasmine.php:
<div id="content">
    <h2>Hello, Please let me know which date you are looking for </h2>
    <div><label style="font-size: 14pt; font-family: Verdana;">Posting Date: </label></div><br />
    <input type="text" id="date" value= "<?php echo $_GET['id']?>" class="css-input" placeholder="Posting Date..." readonly="readonly" /><br /><br />

    <input type="button" id="validate" value="Let's work!" class="btn" /> 
    <input type="button" id="clear" value="Wanna go Again?" class="btn" />
</div>
<div id="contentarea2" style="display: none;">
    <h2>Results:</h2>
    <div class="view_alerts">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                     Code
                </td>
                <td>
                    # Posted
                </td>

            </tr>
            <tbody id="view_alerts_tbody">

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

In Jasmine, I get the date already written for me from `file.php`, all I need to do is click the button so it could show me a table, is there a way, that it clicks the button on its own if theres a date written, so when I go on that link, it already puts the date and takes me to the table in `jasmine.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the code from the answer above the if statement here should evaluate the input fields value (id is '#date').  An empty value will default to false hence the ! before the selector.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
    {
    if(!$('#date').val()) {
        jQuery("#Your-Button-ID").click();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below JQuery code for your purpose. When page load is completed (i.e. Page is ready)

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function()
 {
 jQuery("#Your-Button-ID").click();
 });
```

Comment: How can I do an if statement that if date is not null to execute the jquery and if it is, it'll ignore the jquery?